# How to set Holo style for android radiobutton

Tags: android, radio-button, android-holo-everywhere

I have set the `radiobutton` `drawble` to make it appears to the right of the text.
But I want to set the `Holo` style for this radiobutton. how ?

code:

```
<RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/rb2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:button="@null"
   android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
   android:paddingLeft="40dip"
   android:tag="2"
   android:text="@string/Conflict_of_intrest" />
```

Comment: set a Holo background image in a radio button ..

Answer (score 1):

Use `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle` as right-drawable while disabling default radio button look(`android:button="@null"`)

```
<style name="rtlRadioBtn" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
     <item name="android:button">@null</item>
     <item name="android:drawableRight">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle</item>
     <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
Drawable radio;

try {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Theme theme = getContext().getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle, typedValue, true);
    radio = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(typedValue.resourceId);
} catch (Exception e) {
    radio = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
}
```

XML:

```
?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle
```